# creating a table with default value

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a table with one row with default values​​ then it will update.

I cannot show images, because :
"You need at least 10 reputation to post images.",I am sorry:

from:

[image]

to:

[image]

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
.
.
.

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SETTING = "CREATE TABLE " + 
MYSETTING + "(" + ID_SETTING + " INTEGER 0," + 
        PIC_SETTING + " INTEGER DEFAULT 1," + WITH_PIC_SETTING + " INTEGER DEFAULT 7," + 
        WITHOUT_PIC_SETTING + " INTEGER DEFAULT 10" + ")"; 

//my update function
public void updateSetting(int key,int pic , int number_with_pic , int number_without_pic){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID_SETTING, key);
    values.put(PIC_SETTING, pic);
    values.put(WITH_PIC_SETTING, number_with_pic);
    values.put(WITHOUT_PIC_SETTING, number_without_pic);
    db.update(MYSETTING, values, ID_SETTING + " = ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(key)});
}
```

---

```
public class Settings extends Fragment {
DataBaseHelper db ;
ArrayList<Integer> arraysetting ;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_2,container,false);
    db = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
    db.updateSetting(0, 4, 3, 2);
    //arraysetting = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //arraysetting.addAll(db.getAllSetting());

    return  view;
}
}
```

---

my errors:

```
01-23 01:32:51.201: E/AndroidRuntime(632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-23 01:32:51.201: E/AndroidRuntime(632): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: mysetting: , while compiling: UPDATE mysetting SET pic_setting=?,without_setting=?,with_setting=?,id_setting=? WHERE id_setting = ?

01-23 01:32:51.201: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
```

Comment: Does your `DataBaseHelper` override `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)`?

Comment: yes, db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SETTING);

Comment: Does your logcat show any errors relating to the datbase creating? The error you posted indicates that the table does not exist, indicating there was an issue with creation.

Comment: full my class : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6799829/ full my errors : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6799834/

Comment: check the return value from getActivity as context i think  your activity doesn't attached yet so when you send the context it will be null try to making your database code in OnactivityCreated you here sure that your context is created

Comment: are you using Fragment in support Library ?

Comment: yes,
The problem is not the getactivity. I am sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the table isn't getting created due to a SQL syntax error.

Specifically, I think you are missing a "DEFAULT" in your `ID_SETTING` column definition.

`ID_SETTING + " INTEGER 0,"` should be `ID_SETTING + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0,"`

The other problem I see is that your `onUpgrade()` only drops the tables- it doesn't recreate them. When the database is updated, *only* `onUpgrade()` is called- `onCreate()` will not be called again.

Though `onUpgrade()` shouldn't be getting called, there might be a bug that is causing it to get called, thus dropping your tables.

I would try correcting your `onUpgrade()`, then uninstalling and reinstalling your application.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some suggestions pertaining to `onUpgrade()`.

Comment: ok, but I have not any data when called getAllSetting() function. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6801496/ my errors : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6801535/

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't show you inserting any data anywhere, and that error indicates that you haven't inserted any data.